# link preview not working (shows 301) on shortened bitly links on Facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, http-status-code-301

When posting a link on Facebook, after setting the open graph meta tags (e.g. og:title, og:image) it successfully shows a link preview as I intend it to. However after shortening the link with bit.ly, when I post it on Facebook the link preview becomes "301 moved permanently" with no image. I get the same with tinyurl, are there any specific tags I should be adding here? I have tried refreshing with the sharing debugger, re crawling, trying iterations of the url with http and https and it's all the same result with the short url

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question here for all those in the future who may also have this problem,
I had to actually go into my site settings and turn https redirecting off, and enable both http and https